# Link SCROLLINFO to my scrollbar — WINAPI C++

Tags: c++, winapi, scroll, scrollbar

I have a window with a working default scrollbar.

Now I'd like to link all the code I have to the custom scrollbar created via `CreateWindow`

Here is the procedure that

```
LRESULT CALLBACK InfoProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR, DWORD_PTR) {
    switch (msg) {
        case WM_COMMAND:
        if(wParam == ID_CLOSECROSS){
            if(IsWindowVisible(aboutPanel)) SwitchToWindow(aboutPanel); else SwitchToWindow(howToPanel);
        }   
        break;

        case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:{
            if((short)HIWORD(wParam) > 0){
                SendMessage(hwnd, WM_VSCROLL, VK_UP, 0);
            }else{
                SendMessage(hwnd, WM_VSCROLL, VK_DOWN, 0);
            }
            break;
        }

        case WM_VSCROLL:{
            RECT hrc; GetClientRect(hwnd, &hrc);
            SCROLLINFO si;
            si.cbSize = sizeof (si);
            si.fMask  = SIF_ALL;
            GetScrollInfo (hwnd, SB_VERT, &si);
            int pos;
            yPos = si.nPos;
            switch (LOWORD (wParam)){
                case SB_TOP:        si.nPos = si.nMin;  break;                
                case SB_BOTTOM:     si.nPos = si.nMax;  break;                
                case SB_LINEUP:     si.nPos -= 1;       break;
                case SB_LINEDOWN:   si.nPos += 1;       break;                
                case VK_UP:         si.nPos -= 20;      break;                
                case VK_DOWN:       si.nPos += 20;      break;                
                case SB_PAGEUP:     si.nPos -= si.nPage; break;               
                case SB_PAGEDOWN:   si.nPos += si.nPage; break;               
                case SB_THUMBTRACK: si.nPos = si.nTrackPos; pos = HIWORD(wParam); break;
            }
            si.fMask = SIF_POS;
            SetScrollInfo (hwnd, SB_VERT, &si, TRUE);
            GetScrollInfo (hwnd, SB_VERT, &si);
            if (si.nPos != yPos){                    
                ScrollWindow(centerHowToPanel, 0, scrollSpeed*(yPos-si.nPos), NULL, &hrc);
                // here
                UpdateWindow (centerHowToPanel);
            }
            return 0;
        }

        case WM_SIZE:{
            RECT hrc = { 0 };
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &hrc);
            SCROLLINFO si = { 0 };
            si.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
            si.fMask = SIF_ALL;
            si.nMin = 0;
            si.nMax = 30 * 99 + 21;
            si.nPage = (hrc.bottom - hrc.top);
            si.nPos = yPos;
            si.nTrackPos = 0;
            SetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &si, true);
            // here
        }
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my scrollbar I create in WinMain:

```
howToScroll = CreateWindow(L"SCROLLBAR", NULL, WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|SBS_VERT, 0, 0, 0, 0, howToPanel, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

If I replace each `(Get|Set)ScrollInfo(hwnd, ...)` with `(Get|Set)ScrollInfo(howToScroll, ...)` in the procedure it almost works. I can use scrollbar's arrows, but can't drag it. Also mouse wheel doesn't seem to change custom scrollbar's position.

I tried to use `SetScrollPos(howToScroll, SB_CTL, yPos, 1);` in the procedure at places where is commented `'here'` word but it doesn't help either.

Also when resizing my custom scrollbar doesn't change it's size as default one does.

Just a quick demostration how it works with the default scrollbar.

[image]

And here how it works with the custom one.

[image]

---

---

## Edit 1

I managed to make it scroll!

```
LRESULT CALLBACK InfoProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR, DWORD_PTR) {
    switch (msg) {
        case WM_COMMAND:
        if(wParam == ID_CLOSECROSS){
            if(IsWindowVisible(aboutPanel)) SwitchToWindow(aboutPanel); else SwitchToWindow(howToPanel);
        }   
        break;

        case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:{
            if((short)HIWORD(wParam) > 0){
                SendMessage(hwnd, WM_VSCROLL, VK_UP, 0);
            }else{
                SendMessage(hwnd, WM_VSCROLL, VK_DOWN, 0);
            }
            break;
        }

        case WM_VSCROLL:{
            RECT hrc; GetClientRect(hwnd, &hrc);
            SCROLLINFO si;
            si.cbSize = sizeof (si);
            si.fMask  = SIF_ALL;
            GetScrollInfo (howToScroll, SB_VERT, &si);
            int pos;
            yPos = si.nPos;
            switch (LOWORD (wParam)){
                case SB_TOP:        si.nPos = si.nMin;  break;                
                case SB_BOTTOM:     si.nPos = si.nMax;  break;                
                case SB_LINEUP:     si.nPos -= 1;       break;
                case SB_LINEDOWN:   si.nPos += 1;       break;                
                case VK_UP:         si.nPos -= 20;      break;                
                case VK_DOWN:       si.nPos += 20;      break;                
                case SB_PAGEUP:     si.nPos -= si.nPage; break;               
                case SB_PAGEDOWN:   si.nPos += si.nPage; break;               
                case SB_THUMBTRACK: si.nPos = HIWORD(wParam); break;
            }
            SetScrollPos(howToScroll, SB_CTL, yPos, true);
            si.fMask = SIF_POS;
            SetScrollInfo (howToScroll, SB_VERT, &si, TRUE);
            GetScrollInfo (howToScroll, SB_VERT, &si);
            if (si.nPos != yPos){                    
                ScrollWindow(centerHowToPanel, 0, scrollSpeed*(yPos-si.nPos), NULL, &hrc);
                UpdateWindow (centerHowToPanel);
            }
            return 0;
        }

        case WM_SIZE:{
            RECT hrc = { 0 };
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &hrc);
            SCROLLINFO si = { 0 };
            si.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
            si.fMask = SIF_ALL;
            si.nMin = 0;
            si.nMax = hrc.bottom+40;
            SetScrollRange(howToScroll, SB_CTL, 0, hrc.bottom+40, TRUE);
            si.nPage = (hrc.bottom - hrc.top);
            si.nPos = yPos;
            si.nTrackPos = 0;
            SetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &si, true);
        }
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now it seems like the head of the scroll is not big enough so it doesn't goes to the end of the bar.

[image]

The only thing I need to manage -- the size of the scroll.

---

---

## Edit 2

If I replace every single `SB_VERT` with `SB_CTL` it works as should! Thanks @JonathanPotter for that.

[image]

Comment: what happens when you set the HINST parameter? See here for example with CreateWindowEx https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/create-scroll-bars

Comment: Can you check the value of `lParam` in your `WM_VSCROLL` case? I'm not entirely sure how you've implemented your scrollbar but, if this is *not* the default/standard scrollbar, then it will *not* be `NULL` and you should use that (cast as an `HWND`) in the calls to `GetScrollInfo()` and `SetScrollInfo()`. In this case, you'll also need to get that ***control*** `HWND` in the `WM_SIZE` case. Can you run a test and post the `lParam` value, please?

Comment: @kvr setting last but one argument in scrollbar creation to `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` doesn't make it work.

Comment: @AdrianMole how would you like to get it? As an int?

Comment: @AdrianMole I printed lParam in the console and it equals to 5186818 that is obviously not a NULL.

Comment: I just re-read your question, and your attempts to use the `howToScroll` handle would seem to invalidate my answer - so I deleted it. There may be a few more tricks that need to be added, so I'll think about that and then maybe edit and undelete my answer.

Comment: What window is the custom scroll bar a child of? It will be sending `WM_VSCROLL` messages to its parent.

Comment: The parent is defined like so: `howToPanel = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE|WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME, L"STATIC", L"", WS_CHILD|SS_SUNKEN|SS_CENTER, 0, 0, 0, 0, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);`

Comment: @AdrianMole I edited the post and I am left with the single question. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: In your edited code you still have some calls that use `SB_VERT`. These need to all be changed to `SB_CTL`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter. Yes!!! It works. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JonathanPotter do you know how I can find out when the scrollbar is fullheight so I can hide it?

Comment: You can calculate that from the values of nMax, nMin and nPage.

Comment: @JonathanPotter how exactly can I do that? I printed these values on the console, but I can't make dependencies between them.

Comment: Something like `ShowWindow(howToScroll, (nMin == nMax || nPage > (nMax - nMin)) ? SW_HIDE : SW_SHOW);`

Comment: @JonathanPotter it doesn't seem to work because `nMax` and `nMin` are not being changed.

Comment: Not sure what that means. You're responsible for setting nMax and nMin, so that the scrollbar knows what its range is.